# Select All Friends in Facebook

Tags: facebook, friends

How does one select all friends when trying to invite them into groups, etc.?

Comment: But please don't overdo it with the select all and inviting all your friends to some groups. They removed the option for a reason.. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Click on the invite button, paste this code in to your address bar:

```
 javascript:elms=document.getElementById('friends').getElementsByTagName('li');for(var fid in elms){if(typeof elms[fid] === 'object'){fs.click(elms[fid]);}}
```

and hit enter. All friends will be selected, enjoy!

Comment: Or use the developer tools on your browser to the run the script.

Comment: @andrew Is there any trustworthy method to add all of my friends to a facebook group at once ?

Answer (score 0):

Here you have 2 browser plugins for quickly selecting all your friends (actually 50 at a time, which is the current limit set by Facebook):

- [Facebook Invite All](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/eibdjcmcmfggjoiaaoojhicjnkghbkbe) **for Google Chrome**

  Adds an "toggle all" friends button to Facebook groups, events and pages
- [Select ALL Facebook Friends](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/70384) **for Firefox** (requires [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/748/))

  Easily invite all of your friends to your fan pages, groups, and some apps on Facebook. By default, it will add ALL, but you can select a range if you only want to add a certain number of your friends.

Answer (score 0):

There is Chrome Extension to Invite all Friends to the New Facebook Groups:

[Facebook New Group Inviter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/facebook-new-group-invite/dhhemdhonhlkaoadhbgdnogknjnagplg)

Comment: Garry, it's customary on SE to disclose your affiliation when promotion your own products here.

Comment: Please at least give the name of the Extension. That URL isn't human-readable.